# Error in finding $E(X^2)$ for the Poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, proof-verification, proof-writing, poisson-distribution

I am trying to prove the variance of the Poisson distribution. To do that, I first work out $E(X^2)$. I know there are easier ways to do this.

Let $$X \texttt{~}  Poisson(\lambda)$$

Then,

$$
E(X^2) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} x^2\dfrac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!} $$

and since the first term is 0,
$$= \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} x^2\dfrac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!} $$

$$= \dfrac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^1}{1!} + \sum_{x=2}^{\infty} x^2\dfrac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!} $$

So all I have done is taken the $x=1$ term out of the summation. But I end up with the $e^{-\lambda}\lambda$, and after more manipulation end up with $e^{-\lambda}\lambda + \lambda^2$ instead of the correct $\lambda + \lambda^2$.

Any ideas on where I have gone wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I really don't think you can go from $\sum_{x=2}^{\infty} x^2\dfrac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}$ to $\lambda^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Separating the first term from the sum only makes it more troublesome, but going with what you have, you should do this $$\displaystyle\sum_{x=2}^{\infty} x^2 \dfrac{e
^{-\lambda} \lambda^{x}}{x!}=\displaystyle\sum_{x=2}^{\infty} x\dfrac{e
^{-\lambda} \lambda^{x}}{(x-1)!}$$ $$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad =\displaystyle\sum_{y=1}^{\infty} (y+1)\dfrac{e
^{-\lambda} \lambda^{y+1}}{y!}$$ $$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad =\lambda\displaystyle\sum_{y=1}^{\infty} y\dfrac{e
^{-\lambda} \lambda^{y}}{y!}+\lambda\displaystyle\sum_{y=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{e
^{-\lambda} \lambda^{y}}{y!}$$ $$\qquad \qquad \qquad \ =\lambda^2+\lambda(1-e^{-\lambda})$$
to get the desired manipulation.